# what does exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@4205eb18 does not exist mean

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception, android-windowmanager

I am trying to login into the app but after the login is success and it is about to go to next screen, it restarts. Following is the exception that I guess would have caused  this, as there is no other exception.

```
11-14 15:09:54.841: W/WindowManager(643): Failed looking up window
11-14 15:09:54.841: W/WindowManager(643): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@4205eb18 does not exist
11-14 15:09:54.841: W/WindowManager(643):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7622)
11-14 15:09:54.841: W/WindowManager(643):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7613)
11-14 15:09:54.841: W/WindowManager(643):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1591)
11-14 15:09:54.841: W/WindowManager(643):   at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:417)
11-14 15:09:54.841: W/WindowManager(643):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
11-14 15:09:54.841: I/WindowManager(643): WIN DEATH: null
```

Can anyone tell, what does it mean and if possible how to correct it.

Comment: In what application you trying to log in?

Comment: Is this the only exception logged? It shows one of the components dying, causing binder exception on the client side. I'd look for another exception in the logs.

Comment: what does that mean? where ca n I find the documentation for this exception.

Comment: You should not care, you should rather grep the logs for other exceptions. This particular exception means nothing more than crash of one components communicating via Binder IPC. If you really want to know about binder: http://www.nds.rub.de/media/attachments/files/2012/03/binder.pdf

Comment: please show the piece of code that causing this exception?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219146/failed-looking-up-window-different-behaviors-from-same-app-on-2-galaxy-nexus

Comment: @ code Painters... So you mean that this exception has occured after some other exception has already occured,..?

Comment: Yes. You got an exception which crashed the application/caused win death.

Comment: can someone tell what does this exception mean..?

Answer (score 13):

This may be caused by calling a system API that is not available on your target device. I ran into this issue then trying to call ActivityManager.MemoryInfo.totalMem on a 4.0.x device. I didn't get any compile errors as I was targeting 4.2.2 and ActivityManager.MemoryInfo.totalMem was added in API16 (4.1)

Comment: Thanks for the idea! In my case it was `view.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS);` on a device that doesn't support it (Casio C811 4G). `view.isHapticFeedbackEnabled()` helped.